# Comparing values of two lines based on the Key in a file using awk

Tags: unix, awk

how can I compare and output the "id" and "name" for which the start and end dates has overlap and falls under the same date range.

In the below example row 2 date range overlaps with row 1, similar way row 3 date range overlap with row 4.

For example:

```
row   id      name    start         end
1     AA123   temp1   2020-01-10    2020-04-10
2     AA123   temp1   2020-02-20    2020-03-20
3     AA700   temp4   2019-01-01    2019-02-28
4     AA700   temp4   2018-12-01    2019-04-20
5     BB120   temp5   2021-01-10    2021-02-01
```

Expected Output:

```
id      name
AA123   temp1
AA700   temp4
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Kindly do add your efforts in form of code 
in your question, whichh is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' 'NR==1 || (k=$2) in s && !(e[k]<$4 || $5<s[k]) {print k,$3} 
                   {s[k]=$4; e[k]=$5}' file

id      name
AA123   temp1
AA700   temp4
```

Comment: hi karakfa - thanks for the quick response. when I run the command with my big file I am seeing infinite loop.  cat file.csv |  awk -vFPAT='([^,]*)|("[^"]+")' -vOFS=, '{print $5","$25","$26}' | sort -n -s -k1,1 | awk -v OFS=',' 'NR==1 || $5 in s && !(e[k]<$25 || $26<s[k]) {print $5} {s[$5]=$25; e[$5]=$26}'